# Can I stop people kissing me all the time?

Tags: glitch-2011

People are always kissing me, and more often than not they've got garlic breath, which really gets my mood down. Is there any way of preventing people from kissing me?

Comment: I have this problem irl.

Comment: +1 for using only the tag to keep the question on topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably know this already, but those players are attempting to complete the early quest [Spread the Garlic Love](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Spread_the_Garlic_Love). There's currently no way to block these types of 'social' player to player interactions globally, and given the nature of the game I doubt there will be one any time soon.

Instead, since this is a relatively early quest, you might want to simply avoid areas where new players start, or move to less crowded areas. Other than changing your username to "Stop kissing me" I doubt there will be a better way to prevent this, so I suppose you should just take this as part of the game's humor and go along with it. The mood loss is fairly small anyway, and you won't suffer any penalty until your mood drops below the half way point.

Comment: If I saw anyone with the username "Stop kissing me", I would *immediately* kiss them.

Comment: @fredley Well... yes, you're probably right. I now have an uncontrollable urge to change my username to that just to see what would happen. But then I'd have to keep it for the next 2 months...

Comment: I think if you changed your name to something like tubgirl, then the kisses will stop immediately.

Comment: @yx. Why is that?

Comment: @fredley Google knows - but if you do ask Google about things like tubgirl, your Internet childhood will end.